# Capturing image from webcam in java?

Tags: java, image, webcam, capture

How can I continuously capture images from a webcam?

I want to experiment with object recognition (by maybe using java media framework).

I was thinking of creating two threads

one thread:

- Node 1: capture live image
- Node 2: save image as "1.jpg"
- Node 3: wait 5 seconds
- Node 4: repeat...

other thread:

- Node 1: wait until image is captured
- Node 2: using the "1.jpg" get colors
  from every pixle
- Node 3: save data in arrays
- Node 4: repeat...

Comment: Here is your answer-- [Java Swing program to capture images from webcam tutorial](http://www.tricksmode.com/2013/03/How-To-Capture-Webcam-Images-In-Java-Swings.html)
Slightly modify it and youre done..

Answer (score 49):

This JavaCV implementation works fine.

Code:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.IplImage;

import java.io.File;

import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_core.cvFlip;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.helper.opencv_imgcodecs.cvSaveImage;

public class Test implements Runnable {
    final int INTERVAL = 100;///you may use interval
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");

    public Test() {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void run() {

        new File("images").mkdir();

        FrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0); // 1 for next camera
        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
        IplImage img;
        int i = 0;
        try {
            grabber.start();

            while (true) {
                Frame frame = grabber.grab();

                img = converter.convert(frame);

                //the grabbed frame will be flipped, re-flip to make it right
                cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise

                //save
                cvSaveImage("images" + File.separator + (i++) + "-aa.jpg", img);

                canvas.showImage(converter.convert(img));

                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test gs = new Test();
        Thread th = new Thread(gs);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

There is also [post on configuration for JavaCV](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2017/01/javacv-configuration-in-windows.html)

You can modify the code and be able to save the images in regular interval and do rest of the processing you want.

Comment: +1 You rock!  I was looking for a good open source and supported alternative to JMF for webcam captures in both Windows and Linux.  This works like a charm!  Thank you :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp213892357885346\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Comment: This will work, but the video quality isn't as good as it should be.  See my answer for better video output quality.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am interested how to set it on Windows? Do I need the 3Gb extracted zip? Otherwise my program, using JavaCV on Linux works fine.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko you need OpenCV installed.

Answer (score 36):

Some time ago I've created generic Java library which can be used to take pictures with a PC webcam. The API is very simple, not overfeatured, can work standalone, but also supports additional webcam drivers like OpenIMAJ, JMF, FMJ, LTI-CIVIL, etc, and some IP cameras.

Link to the project is https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

Example code (take picture and save in test.jpg):

```
Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
webcam.open();
BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("test.jpg"));
```

It is also available in Maven Central Repository or as a separate ZIP which includes all required dependencies and 3rd party JARs.

Comment: For ease of getting started this is well worth a look. The code worked great for me, hopefully you also :)

Comment: @Bartosz Firyn : hello I am working with your API. awesome work man!but now I want to know that if zooming in camera supported or not? how to zoom camera using this API?

Comment: @JavaMan, there is no native support for zooming.

Comment: @BartoszFiryn : okay thanks and what about drawing on camera? I want to draw Transparent frame on camera? then it is possible with API?

Comment: @JavaMan, you can draw either on the panel that display view from camera (WebcamPanel) by setting your custom Painter instance, or directly on the image that comes from camera by using WebcamImageTransformer feature. For more details please open the ticket on the Webcam Capture project page on Github since I do not want to explain this in details here on Stack Overflow (too much to write and too few characters to use in comments). The project can be found here https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

Comment: @Elyas Hadizadeh, in case of problems you can always create new issue ticket at https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture where you can also find documentation and examples. Please also bear in mind that this is framework for people rather familiar with Java. In case you are Java newby there are also people willing to help, but you have to learn basics on your own.

Comment: @BartoszFiryn, I do agree with you, i must improve my knowledge, thank you for your reply. :-)

Comment: This is a great library.  It covers all the needs for dynamic webcam picture capture.  It even has motion detection capabilities.  Great option.

Comment: @BartoszFiryn is this library still actively maintained as there seem to be quite a few open issues and the last commit was quite a few months ago? Just asking to see if I should use this library or not, thanks!

Comment: I have used this but i got continues logs in console. How can i stop them like     
                                                                                                                              
2020-10-14 10:31:23.847 DEBUG 7108 --- [scovery-service] c.g.s.w.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver   : Found device Integrated Webcam 0
2020-10-14 10:31:26.847 DEBUG 7108 --- [scovery-service] c.g.s.w.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver   : Searching devices
2020-10-14 10:31:26.850 DEBUG 7108 --- [scovery-service] c.g.s.w.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver   : Found device Integrated Webcam 0

Answer (score 7):

JMyron is very simple for use.
http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/

```
myron = new JMyron();
myron.start(imgw, imgh);
myron.update();
int[] img = myron.image();
```

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115835/what-is-the-best-method-to-capture-images-from-a-live-video-device-for-use-by-a) is a similar question with some - yet unaccepted - answers. One of them mentions [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/) as a java alternative to JMF.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of goes off of gt_ebuddy's answer using JavaCV, but my video output is at a much higher quality then his answer.  I've also added some other random improvements (such as closing down the program when <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> are pressed, and making sure to close down the resources the program uses properly).

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class HighRes extends JComponent implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
    private static boolean running = false;
    private static int frameWidth = 800;
    private static int frameHeight = 600;
    private static OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
    private static BufferedImage bufImg;

    public HighRes()
    {
        // setup key bindings
        ActionMap actionMap = frame.getRootPane().getActionMap();
        InputMap inputMap = frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

        for (Keys direction : Keys.values())
        {
            actionMap.put(direction.getText(), new KeyBinding(direction.getText()));
            inputMap.put(direction.getKeyStroke(), direction.getText());
        }

        frame.getRootPane().setActionMap(actionMap);
        frame.getRootPane().setInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, inputMap);

        // setup window listener for close action
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                stop();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        HighRes webcam = new HighRes();
        webcam.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {

            grabber.setImageWidth(frameWidth);
            grabber.setImageHeight(frameHeight);
            grabber.start();
            while (running)
            {

                final IplImage cvimg = grabber.grab();
                if (cvimg != null)
                {

                    // cvFlip(cvimg, cvimg, 1); // mirror

                    // show image on window
                    bufImg = cvimg.getBufferedImage();
                    frame.showImage(bufImg);
                }
            }
            grabber.stop();
            grabber.release();
            frame.dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        new Thread(this).start();
        running = true;
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    private class KeyBinding extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public KeyBinding(String text)
        {
            super(text);
            putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, text);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String action = e.getActionCommand();
            if (action.equals(Keys.ESCAPE.toString()) || action.equals(Keys.CTRLC.toString())) stop();
            else System.out.println("Key Binding: " + action);
        }
    }
}

enum Keys
{
    ESCAPE("Escape", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0)),
    CTRLC("Control-C", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK)),
    UP("Up", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0)),
    DOWN("Down", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0)),
    LEFT("Left", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0)),
    RIGHT("Right", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0));

    private String text;
    private KeyStroke keyStroke;

    Keys(String text, KeyStroke keyStroke)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.keyStroke = keyStroke;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

    public KeyStroke getKeyStroke()
    {
        return keyStroke;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Java Webcam SDK](http://www.smaxe.com/product.jsf?id=juv-webcam-sdk) library also.
SDK demo applet is available at [link](http://demo.smaxe.com/juv-na-demo-webcam.html).

Answer (score 3):

I have used JMF on a videoconference application and it worked well on two laptops: one with integrated webcam and another with an old USB webcam. It requires JMF being installed and configured before-hand, but once you're done you can access the hardware via Java code fairly easily.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net). It provides an interface to work with cameras. Moreover, it also provides a set of real-time video processing features, like object tracking and filtering.

Take a look!

Real-time Video Processing Demo:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5mBt0kRYvk

You can use the source below. Just save a frame using **MarvinImageIO.saveImage()** every 5 second.

**Webcam video demo:**

```
public class SimpleVideoTest extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    private MarvinVideoInterface    videoAdapter;
    private MarvinImage             image;
    private MarvinImagePanel        videoPanel;

    public SimpleVideoTest(){
        super("Simple Video Test");
        videoAdapter = new MarvinJavaCVAdapter();
        videoAdapter.connect(0);
        videoPanel = new MarvinImagePanel();
        add(videoPanel);
        new Thread(this).start();
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            // Request a video frame and set into the VideoPanel
            image = videoAdapter.getFrame();
            videoPanel.setImage(image);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleVideoTest t = new SimpleVideoTest();
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

For those who just want to take a single picture:

**WebcamPicture.java**

```
public class WebcamPicture {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            MarvinVideoInterface videoAdapter = new MarvinJavaCVAdapter();
            videoAdapter.connect(0);
            MarvinImage image = videoAdapter.getFrame();
            MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/webcam_picture.jpg");
        } catch(MarvinVideoInterfaceException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used Webcam Capture API. You can download it from [here](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/)

```
webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
webcam.open();

if (webcam.isOpen()) { //if web cam open 
    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
    JLabel imageLbl = new JLabel();
    imageLbl.setSize(640, 480);             //show captured image
    imageLbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));

    int showConfirmDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, imageLbl, "Image Viewer", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(""));

    if (showConfirmDialog == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Save Image");
        chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("IMAGES ONLY", "png", "jpeg", "jpg")); //this file extentions are shown
        int showSaveDialog = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (showSaveDialog == 0) {                  //if pressed 'Save' button
            String filePath = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString().replace("\\", "/");
            String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName(); //get user entered file name to save
            ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(filePath + "/" + fileName + ".png"));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation along with the code

Comment: thanks. it's light and instead javacv this one works for me.

Answer (score 2):

http://grack.com/downloads/school/enel619.10/report/java_media_framework.html

Using the Player with Swing

The Player can be easily used in a Swing application as well.  The following code creates a Swing-based TV capture program with the video output displayed in the entire window:

```
import javax.media.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class JMFTest extends JFrame {
    Player _player;
    JMFTest() {
        addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) {
                _player.stop();
                _player.deallocate();
                _player.close();
                System.exit( 0 );
            }
        });
          setExtent( 0, 0, 320, 260 );
        JPanel panel = (JPanel)getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        String mediaFile = "vfw://1";
        try {
            MediaLocator mlr = new MediaLocator( mediaFile );
            _player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mlr );
            if (_player.getVisualComponent() != null)
            panel.add("Center", _player.getVisualComponent());
            if (_player.getControlPanelComponent() != null)
            panel.add("South", _player.getControlPanelComponent());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( "Got exception " + e );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JMFTest jmfTest = new JMFTest();
        jmfTest.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java usually doesn't like accessing hardware, so you will need a driver program of some sort, as goldenmean said.  I've done this on my laptop by finding a command line program that snaps a picture.  Then it's the same as goldenmean explained; you run the command line program from your java program in the takepicture() routine, and the rest of your code runs the same.

Except for the part about reading pixel values into an array, you might be better served by saving the file to BMP, which is nearly that format already, then using the standard java image libraries on it.

Using a command line program adds a dependency to your program and makes it less portable, but so was the webcam, right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the web-cam application software which comes along with the web-cam, or you native windows webcam software can be run in a batch script(windows/dos script) after turning the web cam on(i.e. if it needs an external power supply). In the bacth script , u can add appropriate delay to capture after certain time period. And keep executing the capture command in loop.

I guess this should be possible

-AD

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty nice interface for this in [processing](http://processing.org), which is kind of a [pidgin](http://www.flight404.com/_videos/pigeonCam.mov) java designed for graphics. It gets used in some image recognition work, such as that link.

Depending on what you need out of it, you might be able to load the video library that's used there in java, or if you're just playing around with it you might be able to get by using processing itself.

Answer (score 0):

FMJ can do this, as can the supporting library it uses, LTI-CIVIL.  Both are on sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

Recommand using FMJ for multimedia relatived java app.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JMyron [How To Use Webcam Using Java](http://howto-java.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-use-webcam-using-java.html). I think using JMyron is the easiest way to access a webcam using java. I tried to use it with a 64-bit processor, but it gave me an error. It worked just fine on a 32-bit processor, though.