# Best option for capturing audio and video online

Tags: javascript, video-capture, audio-recording

We are looking for various options which will help us to record audio and video through web on various platforms including iPhone and iPad? Recorded media will be saved on the server. Any suggestions would be helpful... We are looking for a cross browser approach.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: If you find a review helpful, you should +1 their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say, but the only way to do it on desktop in a cross-browser fashion would be Adobe Flash. On iOS you need to develop Apps for that.

HTML5 will provide Device API at some point of future to achieve your goal.

Comment: HTML5 support playback of audio and video. Do you have further reading of it supporting input of audio and video? Thanks.

Comment: Just Google for "HTML5 Device API." You will find spec draft, discussion and so on.

Comment: My guess would be if HTML5 ever does have a device input, then JavaScript will also include some sort of interface.  Still, Flash is not the only way to do it on the desktop; as you can see in my answer Java and other 3rd party programming interfaces can also do the job.  Flash is just more common.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Flash. Flash can access your webcam and microphone.

Of course, Flash won't fly on iDevices.

There, you'll need to write a native app. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to gain hardware control, you'll most likely need a native application that can access the hardware drivers and API.

My guess is that Java may be able to do the job.

Here's another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java) that may have an embedded solution.

**Nevermind**: iFamily doesn't support Java either