# Solution to capture the webcam images through command line on windows using java

Tags: java

Need to do it without using any swing or other GUI as background process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here: 
[Capturing image from webcam in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java)

If that helps you, you could just create a .jar file and execute it from the comandline, or use a batch. You dont need to use gui, your camera can just record and save the information on the disk without displaying it in the screen. Have a look at that link.