# Simplest way to take a webcam picture using java

Tags: java, webcam

I'm making a program in java. I'd like to be able to take pictures from the client's webcam. I've been looking around, i found some APIs, but i can't really make heads of tails of what I downloaded. Anyone know a really simple way to take pictures in java? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would go with [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) or [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/), they seem to be the big names in this sort of thing.  There is a somewhat-similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java) that contains a few more options, if both of those are a little too "heavy" for you.  It might be worth it to give one of them a shot.

EDIT: [JMyron](http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/) might be what you're looking for, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383406/949067).

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do it using [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/):

```
MarvinVideoInterface videoAdapter = new MarvinJavaCVAdapter();
videoAdapter.connect(0);
MarvinImage image = videoAdapter.getFrame();
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/webcam_picture.jpg");
```