# Using a webcam in a java application

Tags: java, netbeans, webcam

I am using netbeans IDE 7.1.1
I'm making the application capture an image from a webcam, but my problem is that when I run that application first time it gives me proper output but when I run the same application again, it gives me this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not connect to capture device
javax.media.NoDataSourceException: Error instantiating class: com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.DataSource : java.io.IOException: Could not connect to capture device
    at javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(Manager.java:1012)
```

can anyone tell me why this is happening?

my code is:

```
             /* Grab the default web cam*/
             MediaLocator ml = new MediaLocator("vfw://0");

        /* Create my data source */
        DataSource ds = Manager.createDataSource(ml);

        requestFormatResolution(ds);

        /* Create & start my player */
        Player p = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ds);

        p.start();
            Component videoScreen = p.getVisualComponent();
```

Comment: It seems like you're not closing the resource.  Are you sure you've included all relevant bits of code (including the closing of your `Player`)?

Comment: no in whole application I cannot close any resource is it necessary to close the resource ... here can I close only player or all resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your `Player` and deallocate it as well.

Simply do the following:

```
player.close();
player.deallocate();
```

For more details of these methods, look at the API ( [close()](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr927/javax/media/Controller.html#close%28%29) and [deallocate()](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr927/javax/media/Controller.html#deallocate%28%29) ).

Comment: It works but it automatically capture the image and stops. how to capture image on click?

Comment: Implement a `ActionListener` to your click event, and once you are done with that, then call the above two lines. Remember , they are to be called only when you are done with your `Player` resources.

Comment: but the button for capture image is inbuilt in video screen?  how should I implement action listener for that?

Comment: I haven't actually worked with it. You can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java) and [this](http://sunjava-expert.blogspot.in/2011/05/capture-image-from-webcam-java-code.html) for further help. Maybe using some library might ease your work.

Comment: hey Kazekage thanks for the help. Its working fine as I click it is capturing image. :)

Comment: @Jayashri you might want to upvote the answer as well, if it was helpful. :-)