# Java with usb cam on linux: device not opening

Tags: linux, webcam

I am trying to make pictures with a java programm under linux.
I have a normal usb cam, eclipse, java 7
....
i tried nearly all of the thread
[Capturing image from webcam in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java?rq=1)

but nothing want to show me something....

With the Java Webcam SDK library
http://www.smaxe.com/product.jsf?id=juv-webcam-sdk

i came to the point where i can choose my usb-cam out of a list. But than the source tells me:

Failed to open device.

== same with the running... app under eclipse????

How to see something.
I like to use this pics... in a neural net...this is good ...this i like ....

Thx a lot Andy

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to understand what your actual issue is. Please rephrase your question, try to express in a more clear way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your code ;-)