# Java net-beans - capture image using webcam if user login failed

Tags: java

I want to implement a java application, There is a login form and when user login failed then capture the user's image using default webcam and store it in a folder.

How can develop it?

I found some [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qpt-CUuTJkY) related to this topic.

Comment: Can we know what have you tried about the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much, finally I made it :) using this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Link to the project is https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

More Refence - [Capturing image from webcam in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java)

YouTube Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BHyL_XK8YQ

Example code (take picture and save in test.jpg):

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


   //Use try-catch block in the main method OR in any method & call that method in the main method
   try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        //infoBox("Hello", "Beta");
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.open();
        BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("test.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```