# Is there any sample example of Webcam integration in java

Tags: java

I am creating one swing GUI. In which I have to integrate a Web cam.How should I do that ?

Comment: Similar question here: [link text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115835/what-is-the-best-method-to-capture-images-from-a-live-video-device-for-use-by-a)

Answer (score 0):

Try [lti-civil](http://lti-civil.org)