# java:web cam application

Tags: java, webcam

I am looking to do develop the following application. How to proceed?

1. Scan the system for installed webcams and their supported video modes.
2. Let the user select a cam and a video mode.
3. Displays a video of the camera.
4. Starts a frame grabber/processor, it doesn't have to do nothing for now. I want to have the possibility to elaborate frames or at least one frame every x.
5. Not sure if it's possible but i'd need also a routine to overlay processed frames on the playing video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115835/what-is-the-best-method-to-capture-images-from-a-live-video-device-for-use-by-a) on SO for inspiration.

The [JMF](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jmf/2.0/jmf20-08-guide.pdf) framework supports capturing real-time data, audio or video, as detailed in this [article](http://grack.com/downloads/school/enel619.10/report/java_media_framework.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [LTI-Civil](http://lti-civil.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using [Webcam Capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) project since neither JMF nor LTI-CIVIL are maintained any more. Webcam capture is a cross-platform, open source project hosted on Github. There are plenty of examples, e.g. of how to do things you've asked:

- [How to enumerate webcams and listen for new devices connected](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/example/java/WebcamDiscoveryListenerExample.java)
- [Display video from camera](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/example/java/WebcamPanelExample.java)
- [Enable grabbing and take snapshot on demand](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/example/java/TakeSnaphotFromVideoExample.java)

Unfortunately there is no possibility to overlay image obtained thru Webcam Capture API on the playing video. At least not within the Webcam Capture itself, but you could use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) to do that - it contains example of how this can be done.

Please note that Webcam Capture API can be used on top of the JMF, FMJ, LTI-CIVIL, GStreamer, OpenIMAJ and other.