# How to find if system has attached webcam

Tags: java, hardware, webcam

I want to know if the system has a attached webcam. How should i proceed? I want to do it with java language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find out what type of peripherals are attached to your computer via USB for example you have to understand how USB works.

Here are some interessting Links for you:

[USB Faq](http://www.usb.org/about/faq/ans1/)

[Developer Info](http://www.usb.org/developers)

If you already know what type of camera it could be...you could search the computer for specific driver files. From that point on you can check if it is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but there are similar questions in SO:
[Capture image from Webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115835/what-is-the-best-method-to-capture-images-from-a-live-video-device-for-use-by-a) and [Capture images from video device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115835/what-is-the-best-method-to-capture-images-from-a-live-video-device-for-use-by-a)

Maybe you wanna check them out!