# java capture webcam image

Tags: java, image, webcam, capture, jmf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing image from webcam in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java)

What are the options for capturing image from webcam in java?

I know that JMF is a useful library for this, but it hasn't been updated in the past few years and I would rather not use it.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115835

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be old, but it is quite reliable and simple. Give it a try!

You can find alternatives like [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/), which is API-compatible with JMF.

[Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) is very good too.

Answer (score 2):

This JavaCV implementation works fine.

**CODE:**

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;

import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;

public class CaptureImage {
    private static void captureFrame() {
        // 0-default camera, 1 - next...so on
        final OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
        try {
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img = grabber.grab();
            if (img != null) {
                cvSaveImage("capture.jpg", img);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        captureFrame();
    }
}
```

There is also [post on viewing live video](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/javacv-capture-save-flip-show-live.html) from Camera .And [configuration for JavaCV :](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/opencv-javacv-eclipse-project.html) 
You can modify the codes and be able to save the images in regular interval and do rest of the processing you want.